# Dynamically change a value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change dinamically the value in one parragraph. Every time the Button is clicked it should increse the value and show it in the HTML, but it does not change, I have search around and have not found an answer,

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>

<p id="change">My first paragraph.</p>

<button type="button"  onclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>



<script>
var pos = 1;
function myFunction() {
 pos++;
}
document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = pos;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to change the innerHTML inside the click function as well, otherwise it never changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pos = 1;
function myFunction() {
    pos++;
    document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = pos;
}
```

demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/h5Lhxs6q/)

Comment: glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var pos = 1;
function myFunction() {
pos++;
document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = pos;
}
```

You weren't changing the innerHTML in the function.